# Change typescript setting in visual studio 2015 RTM(apache cordova project)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I was building a Apache cordova project using typescript, in version  2015 RC everything was good, but today i upgraded to 2015 RTM and getting an error to target to ECMAScript 5 and above because i am using getter.

```
   get isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {

        return !!(utils.localStorageHandler.get(storageNames.accessToken) && utils.localStorageHandler.get(storageNames.accessToken) != '')

    }
```

the problem is i cannot find the place from which i can change the ECMA target in visual studio 2015 RTM

Please help me with the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RTM 2015 will pick up a `tsconfig.json` if it exists in your project. Where ever you put this in the project will become the Typescript `root`. Turn on Typescript Virtual Projects to see what your typescript structure is like. `Tools > Options > Text Editor > TypeScript > Project > General > Virtual Projects in Solution Explorer`

Example `tsconfig.json` which I placed in the `scripts` folder.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "out": "www/scripts/appBundle.js",
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

When I upgraded from RC to RTM I actually created a new project and moved all my code across. But I did notice the TypeScript version has changed from 1.4 to 1.5 in the project file.

There did also use to be XML tags for the typescript version and target in the project file, but these seem to have largely gone.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json , is more detailed configuration

Answer (score 0):

To set the TypeScript ECMAScript version in VS2015 RTM:

1. Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer
2. Click on the 'TypeScript Build' tab on the left side
3. The first option is a drop-down list for 'ECMAScript version' - for me, it shows v3, v5 and v6

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure you're using a Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova project when you do this? I've never seen these options in the project properties for a Cordova project.

Comment: this option is in typescript project not cordova